# How to retrieve data from firebase for if else condition in java

Tags: java, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I tried to make a different condition based on firebase database data. for example if the "Status" field data has value "Aktif" then the marker color will change to blue and when the "Status" value change into "Nonaktif" then the marker color will change into red.  I already to use this code, but when tried to run it have the problem "error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Context".
So how can i fix this problem? i will put the database structure here [Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwjwF.jpg)

```
private NavigationView navigationView;
private TextView namapengguna, emailpengguna;
private ImageView imageView2;
private View headerView;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

MapView mapView;
public MapboxMap mapboxMap;
private LocationManager manager;
private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
private LocationComponent locationComponent;
Marker myMarker;
private final int MIN_TIME = 1000;
private final int MIN_DISTANCE = 1;


private FirebaseUser user;
private DatabaseReference root;
private StorageReference reference;
private String userID;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Mapbox.getInstance(this,"pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFuZGlrYW1lZGlhbWFydGEiLCJhIjoiY2ttb2o1MWQ2MHp5cDJ3bHcyM3RkN2VvdiJ9.VOmbzomxo3nMMWLcmF2l0g");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    namapengguna = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.namalengkap);
    emailpengguna = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailpengguna);

    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    userID = user.getUid();

    root.child("Users").child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            User userProfile = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if (userProfile != null) {
                String fullName = userProfile.fullname;
                String email = userProfile.email;

                namapengguna.setText(fullName);
                emailpengguna.setText(email);
                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")){
                    String image2 =snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image2).into(imageView2);
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Terjadi Kesalahan Pada Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
        public void ClickMenu(View view) {

    openDrawer(drawerLayout);
}

public static void openDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

public void ClickLogo(View view) {
    closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
}

public static void closeDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}

public void ClickHome(View view) {
    recreate();
}

public void ClickUtama(View view) {
    redirectActivity(this, Utama.class);
}

public void ClickAboutUs(View view) {
    redirectActivity(this, AboutUs.class);
}

public void ClickLogout(View view) {
    logout(this);
}


public static void logout(Activity activity) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle("Logout");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to logout?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            activity.finishAffinity();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.show();

}

public static void redirectActivity(Activity activity, Class aClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, aClass);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
    root.child("otoped").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("otoped").orderByChild("Status").equalTo("0");
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            MyLocation location = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyLocation.class);
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

            if (q != null){
                myMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(IconFactory.getInstance(this).fromResource(R.drawable.ic_markerbiru)));
                myMarker.setPosition(loc);

            }else{
                myMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(IconFactory.getInstance(this).fromResource(R.drawable.markerblue)).position(loc).title("Otoped1"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
            enableLocationComponent(style);
            Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_baseline_location_on_24,null);
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);

        }
    });

}

private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(Dashboard.this)){
        LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
                LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(Dashboard.this, loadedMapStyle).build());

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            return;
        }
        locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
        locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager((PermissionsListener) this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);

    }
}



        @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    if (location != null){
        saveLocation(location);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
        private void saveLocation(Location location) {
            root.child("otoped").setValue(location);
        }
    }
```

I Got problem when tried to edit this code

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
    root.child("otoped").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("otoped").orderByChild("Status").equalTo("0");
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            MyLocation location = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyLocation.class);
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

            if (q != null){
                myMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(IconFactory.getInstance(this).fromResource(R.drawable.ic_markerbiru)));
                myMarker.setPosition(loc);

            }else{
                myMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(IconFactory.getInstance(this).fromResource(R.drawable.markerblue)).position(loc).title("Otoped1"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the area where the error is coming from?

Comment: i already edited the code and added the error